# LocalStorage won't save properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem where the value of the localStorage item won't get saved.
I have no idea why, it's fine untill I refresh.
The variable / local storage item is "logged".

Here is my code : `HTML and JavaScript` https://pastebin.com/Z6JjhyEd

Thank you.

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: It's too long, it can't fit.

Comment: You are supposed to find the minimal bit of code, which is sufficient to reproduce problem. Then you can post it here.

Comment: share the only relevant part which will be useful to debug the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, at the beginning of the javascript code, you have to store and retrieve local storage for 'logged' by checking if it exists or not:

```
 if(localStorage.getItem("logged") !== undefined) {
    logged = localStorage.getItem("logged");
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem("logged", logged);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the applied the changes and it works now.